# Passing Repeat Index Parameter into a Validations Phase Listener

Tags: xpages

I have a repeat control with links to various XPages. I have validations set at the individual field level. I'm trying to find a way to disable all validations if a user navigates to a previous link (page). One idea I came across was using a phase listener. I tried passing a repeatIndex parameter to the phase listener to determine whether or not to disable validations (if repeatIndex < currentPageIndex then disable validations). However, it does not appear that the repeatIndex  is being passed when the link is clicked:

```xml
<xp:repeat
    id="Repeat"
    indexVar="repeatIndex"
    rows="30"
    var="repeatData">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:["Link 1", "Link 2"];}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:link
        escape="true"
        text="#{javascript:repeatData}"
        id="Link">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
        </xp:eventHandler>
        <xp:this.parameters>
            <xp:parameter
                name="repeatIndex">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:repeatIndex;}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:parameter>
        </xp:this.parameters>
    </xp:link>
</xp:repeat>
```

Is it possible to pass the repeatIndex to the phase listener somehow? Is there a better way to go about this? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the server-side is concerned, standard repeat controls only contain a single set of components. There is no index available outside the repeat, a row is set up and destroyed as it is iterated.

If your check for whether or not validation should be enabled depends on something available for the row, you can compute the `disableValidators` or `immediate` properties on the link's eventHandler. But bear in mind the calculation needs to happen server-side and pass the result to the browser *when the page is rendered*, so you won't be able to take into account any changes made since that part of the page was last passed to the browser.

If you want to access the repeat from outside, you can set `repeatControls="true"`, which basically reproduces a set of components for each element of the repeat when the page's component tree (server-side map of the page) is loaded. You can then set the `id` property as "Link#{repeatData}", so you get Link0, Link1 etc. But because the sets of components are hard-coded, you won't be able to use pagers to change what data each row is bound to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm going to play around with setting the repeatContros="true" and compute the id of the links.